# Testing BackboneJs Sinon

Tags: backbone.js, sinon

I am trying to check my method in my Backbone class. This method works but I need to write a unit test with mochaJS and SinonJS

```
describe("Foodtype View", function () {

    before(function () {
        this.$fixture = $("<div id='note-view-fixture'></div>");
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        // Empty out and rebind the fixture for each run.
        this.$fixture.empty().appendTo($("#fixtures"));
        this.spy = sinon.spy();

        var a=[{"id":1,"name":"Pizza","lastModificationDate":"2017-02-03T09:01:58.754Z"}];
        this.view = new app.FoodtypeView({
            el: this.$fixture,
            collection: new app.FoodtypeCollection(a)
        });
    });

    after(function () {
        // Remove all subfixtures after test suite finishes.
        $("#fixtures").empty();
    });

    it("Adding models", function () {
        this.view.addNewFoodtype(this.spy);
    });
```

On view method addNewFoodtype

```
        addNewFoodtype: function () {

            var newFoodtype = $('#newFoodtype').val();

            if (newFoodtype == "") {
                console.log("Wpisz nazwę Typu jedzenia !!");
            } else {
                var newFoodtypeModel = new app.Foodtype({"name": _.escape(newFoodtype)});
                this.collection.add(newFoodtypeModel);
            }
        }
```

1. How to check to my method add model in collection?
2. How to pass the parameter `var newFoodtype = $('#newFoodtype').val();` in my view?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for collection `findWhere` method returns model with `name` equal to your mock;
2. Add `<select>` with id `newFoodtype` to your mocks, that has required option selected.